# Forgotten usage

Tags: present-progressive

Can I say to my friend that,

"I have forgotten to bring Sandwich" in the present tense? Is the 'I have forgotten' usage is correct one?

Comment: This sentence works if you have a sandwich (or something else) named Sandwich.

Comment: @snailboat One assumes that Sandwich is the some hypothetical third friend, who is absent.

Comment: I suspect "I forgot" is much more common here, but yes, this sounds perfectly grammatical and natural (except that you need a "my" or "a" before sandwich).

Comment: I don't think "I forgot" is more common here (in the UK)

Comment: By the way, there is no "progressive" in this question. The form used is usually called the "perfect".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You might want to visit our sister site, English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is very helpful in answering basic questions.

Answer (score 4):

"I have forgotten" is absolutely grammatical and normal. But you need "a sandwich" (or "the sandwich" if you are talking about a specific sandwich known to you and your hearer).